# plane angle calculation problem

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

in calculating the angle between the plane $2x + y -2z +4 = 0$ and $z$ axis I got that the angle between the normal and $z$ axis is $131.81$. however if I take $90°$ minus that I get a negative angle or should I take $180°$ minus said angle?

Comment: It should be $131.81-90$.

Comment: what do you means for ''z plane''? Is it the plane orthogonal to $z$ axis?

Comment: @KittyL why? what's the logic here?

Comment: it is either $\cos^{-1}(-2/3) = 131.81^\circ$ or $48.19^\circ$

Comment: The angle between the normal vector of the plane and z-axis is either $131.81^\circ$ or $48.19^\circ$, depending on how to look at it. Then again depending on how you look at it, going from the normal direction to the plane direction, you either add $90^\circ$ (farther from $z$), or minus $90^\circ$ (backward towards $z$).

Comment: but -90 gives you 41.81....this is totally incoherent

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Usually the searched angle is the **acute** angle.

If $\mathbf {n}$ is the normal vector to the plane and $\mathbf{v}$ the dirctor vector of the stright line, then the angle $\theta$ betwen the plane and the line is:
$$
\theta=\arcsin \dfrac{|\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{n}|}{|\mathbf{v}|\mathbf{n}|}
$$
that i your case gives $\theta = 41,81 °$