# Calculation of subtended plane angle (with integral)

Tags: calculus, plane-geometry, angle

(I found [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193665/347062) unhelpful.)

Here is a sketch of a situation that pertains to my question:

[image: Cartesian plane]

- $f\left( x\right)$ is a parabola of the form $y = x^2 - 4x + 6 = \left( x-2 \right) ^2 +2$ in the $xy$-plane for $x \in \left[ 0,4 \right]$
- $f\left( x \right)$ has two endpoints: $\left( 0,0 \right)$ and $\left( a, f\left( a \right) \right) = \left( 4,6 \right)$
- The third point of significance on $f \left( x \right)$ is $\left( b, f \left( b \right) \right) = \left( \sqrt 6, 12-4\sqrt 6 \right)$, where the line tangent to $f \left( x \right)$ that also intercepts the origin has smallest slope
- $\alpha$ is the angle between the $y$-axis and the line that connects the origin and $\left( a, f\left( a \right) \right)$
- $\beta$ is the angle between the $y$-axis and the line that connects the origin and $\left( b, f\left( b \right) \right)$

My question is **which angle ($\alpha$, $\beta$, or another) is the angle that $f\left( x \right)$ subtends with respect to the origin, and why?**

---

Also, if possible, could you use this as an example of how to calculate subtended plane angle using the formula

$$\theta = \int \frac{\hat r \cdot \hat n}{r} \, d\ell$$

as outlined by the sketch below:

[image: vector]

Comment: I don't see the angle you are interested in $\alpha$ ? $\beta$ ? Another one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie What? I think that you might have left some words out of that sentence (it's a fragment).

Comment: @JeanMarie I am asking which angle is the angle subtended by the parabola with respect to the origin. I suspect that it is ether $\alpha$ or $\beta$, but I suppose that it could be an entirely different angle.

Comment: I suspect that you have to extend you parabola to the left in order to have a second tangent...

Comment: It is certainly not angle $\alpha$.

Comment: @JeanMarie  I included it because if I were attempting to calculate the angle that the line $y=5$ for $x\in \left[ 0,4\right]$ subtends with respect to the origin, I would obviously reference the endpoints.  The same holds for curvy functions like $y=\cos x +4$ on the interval $\left[ 0, 2\pi\right]$.  This is why I referenced the endpoints of the parabola—I figured it was plausible that where a curve starts and stops contributes to the definition of the angle it subtends with respect to a point.